# Google Apps Script: Creating and populating a nested JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script

I would like to create a JSON object with the following structure:

```
var exec_log = {
    total_correct: 0,
    total_error: 0,
    [exec_detail: {
      timestamp: "1a",
      script: "New Deal",
      type: "Bot",
      id: "2a",
      pair: "3a",
      status: "4a",
      message: "5a"
    },
      exec_detail: {
      timestamp: "1a",
      script: "New Deal",
      type: "Bot",
      id: "2a",
      pair: "3a",
      status: "4a",
      message: "5a"
    },
   ...]
  }
```

However I don't know how to create an array of objects inside an object or how to access them to populate them correctly.

Current code:

So far I have achieved this but I'm sure the array is not defined correctly and I suspect that I have to create an external array and push it inside the exec_log object.. **Should I define 2 separated objects and push one inside the other?**

```
function StartNewDeal(filterAPC){ 
  var exec_log = {
    total_correct: 0,
    total_error: 0,
    exec_detail: {
      timestamp: "",
      script: "New Deal",
      type: "Bot",
      id: "",
      pair: "",
      status: "",
      message: ""
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < filterAPC.length; i++){
    Logger.log("Passing botID: " + filterAPC[i][1])
    var new_deal = StartDeal(filterAPC[i][1]);

    var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    
    exec_log.exec_detail[timestamp[i]] = currentDate;
    exec.log.exec_detail[id[i]] = filterAPC[i][1];
    exec_log.exec_detail[pair[i]] = new_deal.pair;
    
    if(new_deal.valid == false){
      exec_log.exec_detail[status[i]] = "Error";
      exec_log.exec_detail[message[i]] = new_deal.json;
      exec.log.total_error = exec.log.total_error + 1;
      
    }else{
      exec_log.exec_detail[status[i]] = "Completed";
      exec_log.exec_detail[message[i]] = "Completed";
      exec.log.total_correct = exec.log.total_correct + 1;
    }

  }

  return exec_log;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createObject() {
  let obj={property1:'value1',property2:'value2',property3:[],property4:[],property5:'value5',property6:'value6'};
  for(let i=0;i<2;i++) {
    let iObj={};
      for(let j=0;j<5;j++) {
       iObj['item'+j]='donkey'+j;  
      }
    obj.property3.push(iObj);
    obj.property4.push(iObj);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea>' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '</textarea>'), "Making an object with no parts");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function StartNewDeal(filterAPC){ 
  var exec_log = {
    total_correct: 0,
    total_error: 0,
    exec_details_list: [] // an array to store your exect_details objects
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < filterAPC.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Passing botID: " + filterAPC[i][1])
    var new_deal = StartDeal(filterAPC[i][1]);
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    var id = filterAPC[i][1];
    var pair = new_deal.pair;
    var status;
    var message;
    var script; // doesn't seem like you're using this
    
    if (new_deal.valid == false){
      status = "Error";
      message = new_deal.json;
      exec.log.total_error = exec.log.total_error + 1;
    } else{
      status = "Completed";
      message = "Completed";
      exec.log.total_correct = exec.log.total_correct + 1;
    }

    exec_log.exec_details_list.push(new ExecDetailObject(timestamp, script, type, id, pair, status, message));
  }
  return exec_log;
}

// A function to create new exec_detail objects
// from your code you don't seem to be using the script property. Not sure if that's intentional
function ExecDetailObject(timestamp, script, type, id, pair, status, message) {
  this.timestampt = timestamp;
  this.script = script;
  this.type = type;
  this.id = id;
  this.pair = pair;
  this.status = status;
  this.message = message;
}
```